# What are my odds of being drafted for US selected service currently?

Tags: united-states, military, armed-conflict, conscription

So this is definitely a slightly paranoia induced question, but it has been on my mind recently (for obvious reasons) and was wondering what my odds are. Age wise I'm primed for the army; I just turned 20 three months ago. However, there are various medical conditions I have which I feel may invalidate me from being drafted. In 2019 I was diagnosed with a stomach ulcer and have yet to receive a follow up appointment to reassess it severity. I also have scoliosis, though it is mild. On top of that I also have diagnosed anxiety disorder and depression, although I've beaten both of these conditions for the most part. Just general information about me: I'm 5'11, 140 lbs., and am currently attending college in the east coast. I know this question may come off as a bit trolly, but I'm genuinely serious and worried about this.

I don't necessarily think the conflict with **that one country** will develop into a war which requires a draft, but given how interrelated and similar this situation is with the Cold War it is certainly a possibility.

Comment: Drafted, meaning compelled to report to a bus station and off to Basic Training in the US Army? I don't want to say 0% (because nothing is ever 0), but actual drafting has not happened since 1972.

Comment: At the moment you would correct to say 0% since we aren't at war and the requirements for a draft are not anywhere close to being met.

Comment: At 5 feet 11 inches and 140 pounds, BMI is honestly right on the margin for what the military would even accept. A three day water fast would probably put you below that number temporarily (but could quite possibly be bad for your health; since there is currently no draft, not recommended).

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to know.

The U.S. has never actually utilized the Selective Service which was established after the last actual conscriptions, for the Vietnam War, ended. It is not at all certain that if conscription were attempted again, that it would use the existing Selective Service system without modification.

It is also hard to know if conscription would even make military sense today. Most active duty military jobs today require more specialized training than they did in Vietnam or when the Selective Service system was established.

We have proportionately fewer riflemen, and proportionately more technicians.

The staffing of the Air Force and Navy is limited as much by our supply of warships and aircraft as it is by personnel. The Navy reserves, Air Force reserves, and Air Force national guard could fill deficits in trained personnel as quickly as we could get warships and military aircraft online.

Marines aren't quite as tightly tied to the ships and weapons system they are designed to deploy with, but this also isn't a service well suited to rapid expansion and contraction with conscripts in the modern era and wouldn't be needed for a European conflict.

Also, the pace of modern warfare is very fast. In modern warfare, the outcome is often a fait accompli if not responded to in a matter of weeks. But to reactivate the Selective Service, draft a certain number of people, and train them to serve from scratch, would take on the order of six months. Also, it would probably take several months to even decide to utilize the Selective Service, six months to get the first draftees into the field once it was activated, and a reasonable expectation that those draftees would be serving at least six months after being trained once called up, so it only really makes sense if a conflict will foreseeably last more than fifteen months. It would take considerable time for a conflict to evolve to the point where this expectation was widely shared enough for politicians to act upon it.

For the last twenty years that the U.S. was at war, it always chose to establish "stop loss orders" prohibiting current service members from leaving at the end of their enlistments, and to mobilize the Army, Marine Corps, Navy and Air Force reserves, the Coast Guard, and the Army and Air Force National Guard, before even seriously considering resorting to military conscription. Experimentation with shifting active duty personnel from one service to another, for example, taking Navy sailors and putting them on a battlefield, were also initiated at a low level in Afghanistan and Iraq, before conscription was considered as an option.

Even in the Army, which would be the military service most likely to conscript new personnel, many positions require skill in diesel mechanics, tank operations, and other specialized military weapons systems that take months beyond basic training to prepare someone to carry out.

Also, even once conscripts are trained to some minimum level in the low skill, high demand specialities that a particular conflict might demand, there is still the problem of getting them to the field. The U.S. military has chronically underinvested in resources to deploy Army soldiers and their equipment to foreign battlefields.
In an all out conventional war with a "near peer" country like Russia or China, ships and unarmed transport aircraft bringing hundreds of thousand of U.S. troops to the front would be very vulnerable targets. Also, since "near peer" nations with whom the U.S. could plausibly be at war also have nuclear weapons for the most part, the number of scenarios of a war so large it triggered a military draft, but small enough so as not to trigger a nuclear war, might be few indeed.

The U.S. is very good at getting missiles and bombs delivered on short notice over long distances, and is much worse at getting tens of thousands of fully equipped soldiers to the field.

For example, one of the staples of the Army's force is the M1 Abrams tank, which weighs about 70 tons. It takes about four weeks to get one by ship from the East Coast to Europe. They are too heavy to be transported over most European rail and car bridges once they are on land. Only one of them can be delivered at a time by a U.S. C-17 transport plane, a resource which is in scarce supply. And the same applies to Patriot Missile defense systems and other heavy weapons systems.

Realistically, the Selective Service is and has been for several decades, an exercise in Security Theater and a sort of loyalty oath for you men in the U.S., rather than an actual military resource of any value.

We also can't plausibly figure out your risk of being drafted until we know how many people the military would decide to conscript, and the nature of those duties.

If the military was merely conscripting people to guard domestic military bases while more seasoned volunteer troops were deployed to the field, the number of conscripts might be modest but the standards in terms of fitness and other limitations on who would be conscripted might also be greatly relaxed.

But if for some reason the U.S. decided that it needed to occupy a territory the size of Texas with five hundred thousand military police (a military specialty that takes somewhat less training than many) the nature of a draft might look very different.

It is hard to devise a realistic scenario in which the Selective Service would be utilized in any of the emerging major military conflicts we are aware of today.

Answer (score 0):

Not to sound harsh but as it is I don't think that you would qualify to even be allowed to join the military much less be drafted. Last time I checked only about 10% of U.S. men of fighting age were considered eligible to join and with what you have going on I'd be very surprised if they accepted you in.

Comment: Didn't take that harshly at all that is exactly what I was hoping to hear

Comment: Of course, any war big enough will result in standards being lowered to meet the demand.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Any war big enough to do it these days has the bigger problem of likely going nuclear.

Comment: @suchiuomizu That is not mutually exclusive at all. Rather the opposite.